# Quick Clarification: Definition of Bijective Function

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

I am very familiar with the concepts of bijective, surjective and injective maps but I am interested in improvising the definition of bijection in a way I have not seen done before. To be clear I will provide the definitions that I use for surjective, injective and bijective although they are the common and generally accepted definitions.

$f:A \to B$ is $surjective$ $\iff$ $\forall y \in B$, $\exists x \in A$ : $f(x) = y$.

$f:A \to B$ is $injective$ $\iff$ $\forall x, y \in A,$ $ f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$

$f:A \to B$ is $bijective$ $\iff$ ($\forall y \in B$, $\exists x \in A$ : $f(x) = y$) $\wedge$ ($\forall x, y \in A,$ $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$)

You can see that the definition provided for bijection is simply the conjunction of surjective and injection.

> My question is, does it suffice to define bijection as such:
>
> $f:A \to B$ is $bijective$ $\iff$ $\forall y \in B$, $\exists! x \in A$ : $f(x) = y$.

Sorry for making a mountain out of a mole hill with this question, the person I usually work with is not here tonight so I have to run my spit ball ideas by you guys! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is **yes**.

Comment: See also http://www.austinmohr.com/Work_files/hw2_4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed equivalent, and in fact often used. Do you need a proof, or can you give it yourself?

Comment: I do not require proof. I spent quite a bit of time googling and could not find a definition other then "one to one and onto". Just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy before using this in what I am working on. Thank you.

Comment: Do note that $\exists!$ is a shorthand anyway (for $\exists x$ and $\forall x_1,x_2 \ldots x_1 = x_2)$.

Comment: This would imply that you have incorrectly chosen your codomain, if I am not mistaken. And @HennoBrandma, I interpret the exclamation point to be shorthand for "unique" which is I believe what you are getting at in your response but why is the RHS $x_{2}$

Comment: @PrinceM Yeah I forgot that $f: A\to B$ so this is not allowed. Good, thanks for clearity this up!

Comment: No problem, thank you for participating and helping troubleshoot my purposed definition.

Comment: @Winther Of course you have to check the definition of $f:A\to B$ means that $f(x)\in B$ (if $x\in A$).

Comment: @PrinceM "there exists a unique $x$" is not a standard quantifier, but a shorthand (if you're working formally). Informally it is a very useful notion, of course. $\forall y \in B \exists! x \in A: f(x) = y$ is defined (!) to mean $\forall y \in B ((\exists x \in A: f(x) = y) \land (\forall x_1, x_2 \in A: (f(x_1) = y \land f(x_2) = y) \rightarrow x_1 = x_2))$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be trivial to prove it to be equivalent. But one should make sure that the concept of the function ($f:A\to B$) means that the values of $f(x)\in B$ (ie check the previous definition of function) - otherwise you'd require that in the definition.

In some cases you use that definition and in other cases you use the definition that it's bijective if it's injective and surjective. Normally you don't repeat the definitions for injective and surjective - that would go against the reason we define stuff.

If it weren't trivial to prove it equivalent the "proper" thing would to prove that the two characterizations of functions are equivalent and then use one of them as definition. Thereby you can use the power of both. Or you should at least at some point prove the definition to be equivalent of the definition that other authors may use (for the same concept).

Answer (score 0):

What is $f?$  If it is a map then 'yes' if $f$ is a function then 'no.'

Comment: Care to elaborate on why?

Comment: If $f:A \to B$  is a map then $Dom(f)=A$ and if $f$ is a function then $Dom(f) \subseteq A.$ So in this case $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq A$

Comment: The definition of function I am working with is "A function from A into B is a subset $Gf$ of the Cartesian product A × B such that the following two statements hold. (i) $\forall x \in A \exists y \in B : (x,y) \in Gf.$  (ii) If $(x,y),(x,z) \in Gf$, then $y = z$. Where  $Gf = x,f(x) \in A×B : x \in A$.

Comment: ** $Gf = \{(x,f(x)) \in A \times B : x \in A \}$

Comment: It is definition of a map. So everything is fine.